# Unable to set selected value within for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble changing the selection of a dropdown within a for loop. 
Here is my code:

```
var costbases = $('[id$="cost_basis"]');

costbases.each(function() {

    var costoption = $('option:selected', this).attr('value');

    if ( costoption == '2' ) {

        $('this option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true);          

    }

});
```

I'm pretty sure this selector is the problem, but I can't figure out the correct syntax:

$('this option[value="0"]')

Comment: Please show all your relevant code

Comment: Maybe `$(this).find('option[value="0"]')` will work

Comment: What is your html?

Comment: `$('this option[value="0"]')` should be `$('option[value="0"]', this)` - `this` is an object but you've put it as a string (so it's looking for DOM element `<this>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find the children and [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the child with the index:

```
$(this).find('option[value="0"]').eq(0).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Why `eq(0)` is needed?

Comment: `find()` returns a collection of elements. So we need to get the first one with `eq(0)`

Comment: But there will be only one with the value `0`.

Comment: After your comment, I tried it with and without the `eq()`. I guess it will return the same either way if there is only one with value 0.

Comment: If your HTML *happens* to only have one entry, then it's the same.  There's no HTML in the question, so we have to *assume* there might be more than one and handle it accordingly.  Providing all the information up-front may have helped.